# Assets\camswitch.cs(7,22): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script in unity to switch between 1st and 3rd person cameras and don't know what I did wrong
I got the error

> "Assets\camswitch.cs(7,22): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

```
using UnityEngine;

public class camswitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    var cam1 : Camera;
    var cam2 : Camera;
                
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam1.enabled = true;
        cam2.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F5))
        {
            Debug.Log("work pls");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is `c#` not `unityscript` .. in c# you don't declare fields as `var name : type;` but rather like `private type name;`

Answer (score 1):

This is not UnityScript but C# so replace this:

```
    var cam1 : Camera;
    var cam2 : Camera;
```

By this:

```
    public Camera cam1;
    public Camera cam2;
```

And everything should be fine then!